# Does faster victory mean lower score?

Tags: civilization-6

I my first playtrough Civ VI I've finished with cultural victory around year 2000 and to be honest it was a close one - I had to attack and conquer Russia, that was close to achieving it before me. While I don't remember my exact final score, in the leaders Hall of Fame I was at about 8-9th place.

In the second playtrough I've won around year 1920, again with cultural victory. This time my country was leading in all fields and (if I'd want to) I could achieve the domination victory many rounds earlier. Yet this time my score was much lower and in the Hall of Fame I've landed on 16th place.

Does it mean that longer game would always bring a higher score? It would be more logical if a quicker victory would rank you higher, not lower.

Both games were played on the same difficulty levels

To clarify: in example if I can achieve a victory in one round (i.e. only one city to conquer) but I'd instead wait few more rounds gathering culture, science etc, before conquering the final city, will my score be lower or higher?

Comment: I don't really think this question has a purpose. Everyone plays differently and can achieve different scores in different times. Someone who's mastered the min/max would be able to hit your score 50 turns earlier maybe. Every game is different, and while a longer game time tends to mean higher score, there's no special formula.

Comment: @n_palum Except for how score is *literally decided by a formula*.

Comment: It's decided by a formula, but time isn't a factor in it. They're asking does more time mean more score or vice versa.

Comment: @n_palum it is: Lets say that to get a victory I need to conquer one more city and I can do it in one turn. If I'd wait 5 more turns doing nothing, but gathering culture, science (maybe getting a new discovery) and THEN I'll conquer the city, will my score be higher or lower?

Comment: It is all dependent on the factors that provide you score. Like I said, there are people who can get a higher score quicker simply through being more efficient.

Comment: @n_palum Yes they can, but in my example would I get higher or lower score? You are just saying that "a good player can get high score quickly". Well, fair enough, but  would the same player get a better score by artistically extending the game (waiting few rounds) or by rushing the victory? Time **MUST** be the factor because with time you get more culture/science/faith BUT at the same time game should penalise you for being a WORSE player (because you could finish much earlier)

Comment: Of course I mean artificially not artistically...

Comment: Well I would still argue longer game doesn't *guarantee* a higher score. What if you're losing?

Comment: Well it seems to doesn't matter if you'll win in the end, at least my example would show that, assuming there is no  penalisation for extending the game or bonus for winning faster.

Comment: @n_palum Nobody said anything about losing.

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not out of consideration. "Does it mean that longer games would *always* bring a higher score". Which isn't a guarantee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at least indirectly.

Score is derived from a [variety of factors](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_(Civ6)#Score), including number of cities, number of technologies, population, and wonders built. Many of these factors are things that you can and often will do more of if you are given more turns.

However, unlike some earlier Civ games, there is no score bonus for winning or ending the game early. This means that the longer you play without actually winning, the more chance you have to earn points and the higher your score will be.

If your goal is getting the highest score possible, you should subjugate your opponents, then spend as many turns as possible building an empire without winning.

Comment: As an addendum there is also no score bonus for higher difficulties like in previous games, which means, if you want to maximize score, you are better off playing on settler difficulty. For comparison, in Civ4 given the exact same game end, your final score would be five times as high on deity than on settler.